# RealmSwiftで配列を保存する方法

Tags: swift2, realm, xcode7

RealmSwiftをつかってToDoアプリを作ろうと思っています

その際、並べ替えもできるようにしたいのですが、その際に配列を使ったほうが楽だろうという考えに達しました。 
というわけで以下のような構造を考えてみました

```
//上のリストではTableに配置する際の順番を、下のObjectではそのタスクの詳細情報を管理する

//タスク名を格納する配列
var list = ["hoge","fuga","miso"]

//realmに格納するObject
class Task: Object{
    dynamic var name: String!

    //タスクの詳細
}
```

しかし、確か（なのですが）RealmSwiftではObject型を継承していない普通の配列を保存することができなかったはずで........

ここだけUserDefaultsを使うべきかと迷っています。 
RealmSwiftで配列を保存できる簡単な方法というのはあるのでしょうか？ 
よろしくお願いいたします

Answer (score 2, accepted):

いろいろやり方はありますが、おっしゃられていることはTaskの順番を記憶したいということですので、大きく２つの方法があります。

まずはオーソドックスに順番を表すプロパティをTaskに持つことです。
この方法はRealmに限らず他のデータベースでもよく使われる基本的なモデリングの考え方になります。

もう一つは、Realmの場合は順番を保持する方法として`List`が使えるので、「タスク名」ではなくタスクそのものを`List`で管理してしまうという方法です。
この方法のメリットは扱いが簡単になることと、先の方法と違って、ソートしなくても良いという点です。

例えば次のような`TaskList`というクラスをもう一つ作ります。

```
class TaskList: Object {
    let list = List<Task>()
}
```

そして、下記のようにして利用します。

```
let task = Task()
task.name = "..."

let taskList = TaskList()
taskList.list.append(task)
```

`list`は順番が保持されていますので、これをそのまま利用すればいいです。

なお、順番を保存するためだけに`NSUserDefaults`を使う、という案は、ややこしくなるだけでメリットはほぼないと思います。

Comment: kishikawa katsumiさん
前回に引き続き、丁寧なご返答ありがとうございます。

Listに関しては、公式の「ほかのオブジェクトとの関連性の構築に使う」という記述から小難しいイメージを持っていたのですが、普通に配列として扱えるのですね........。

参考になります！
ありがとうございました！